# Unexpected value in while loop in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl code:

```
$formatcode='0010';
$binstring='001000111111010110011100000001010100010011001010111111010011100110110000101111';

my @c = (0) x 12;                   
#c0 to c11 all 0

#c12 until all string elements used up
while ($binstring ne "") {push @c,bintodec(substr($binstring,-6,6,""))}

#rest up to c61 are either 0 or leftsync (problem here)
while (@c < 62) {($formatcode =~ /^00/) ? (push @c,0) : (push @c,bintodec($leftsync))}

#c62 is either 0 or formatcode
($formatcode =~ /^00/) ? (push @c,0) : (push @c,bintodec($formatcode));
```

where

```
sub bintodec {              #crude binary to decimal converter
    my $bin = shift;        #value to convert
    my $dec = 0;
    while (length($bin) > 0) {$dec = 2*$dec + substr($bin,0,1); $bin = substr($bin,1)}
    return $dec;
}
```

Can someone please tell me why after executing `while (@c < 62)` segment I end up with

`@c=0000000000004748381963101920128226380000000000000000000000000000000000000`   ?

Why is the length of `@c` not 62 ?

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: That is not the value of `@c`, that is likely the value that appears when you print the contents of `@c`, which would be all of its elements concatenated together. Try `print "$_\n" for @c;` to separate each element with a newline, or [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.pl/Data::Dumper) for more general structure debugging.

Comment: Thanks @Grinnz you´re right. That's not the value of @c but of all elements concatenated. I saw these elements before but I was misinterpreting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@c` contains 63 elements. They are:

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47, 48, 38, 19, 63, 10, 19, 20, 1, 28, 22, 63, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

The 63rd is from the final push outside of the loop.

It's also possibly you wanted 62 (63) *digits*. If that's the case either use a string instead of an array, or split the results of bin2dec using `split //, bin2dec(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Helena, your final `push` adds extra element into array. You could convert *bin* to *dec* with following code

```
sub bin2dec {
    my $bin = shift;

    my $dec = 0;

    map { $dec <<= 1; $dec += $_ } split '', $bin;

    return $dec;
}
```